# How to run default rake tasks in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, rakefile

Here's a layup for someone...

Back in Rails <= 4 days we'd run our test suite by simply typing `$ rake` at the command line, thanks to defaults in Rakefile:

```
task default: [:rubocop, :spec, :teaspoon]
```

but in Rails 5 it's not so apparent how to run default rake tasks now that `rake` has been replaced by `rails`. `rails` alone gives a list of possible commands rails responds to but doesn't run the specs. `rails test` seems logical but it tries to run minitest which we don't use. `rails spec` will run Rspec but not **teaspoon** or **rubocop**.

Where did this go?  And why is something so apparently simple so hard for me to look up myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails default`
executes those tasks for me on Rails 5.2.1, though I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new `rake` task that runs the other ones:

lib/tasks/my_extensions.rake

```
task :my_test do
  Rake::Task[:foo].invoke
  Rake::Task[:bar].invoke
end
# or the short version:
# task my_test: [:foo, :bar]

task :foo do
  puts "FOO"
end

task :bar do
  puts "BAR"
end
```

Run `rails my_test` and you will see `FOO` and `BAR` printed in your console.

If you don't know **where** to place the file to write the code above, check your `/Rakefile`:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require_relative 'config/application'

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

It says to write them inside `lib/tasks` and end them with `.rake`, you don't need to require them. In your specific question, change my code from `:foo` and `:bar` to your specific tasks `:rubocop :spec :teaspoon`.

However, it looks like you are doing some BDD or TDD cycle. Check out [rails Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), it might help you better. I use it in my project and it works perfectly.